# How does deep snow affect carrying on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, weather, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, snow

Thinking about the snow in Boston and the discussion at Shabbos 5a, if there was more than 10 tefakim (handbreadths) of snow on the ground, would a reshus hayachad (private domain) extend from the soil or the top of the snow?

If the streets were plowed, could one drag a sled along the top of the snow 10 tefakim plus higher than the street without violating Shabbos, or throw a snowball that would land on the top of the snow?

Comment: Very intriguing question!

Comment: +1 The same question can be applied to Techumin, which many say doesn't apply above 10 tefachim.

Comment: Someone suggested that I would figure out the answer if I study the discussions about rishusim and water.  Haven't done that yet, though.

Comment: @BruceJames, I think you mean Reshut Harabim in your question. A Reshut Hayachid extends to the "sky', always. it's a Reshut haRabim that only extends 10 tefachim up.

Comment: As someone who has lived in the Boston Area practically all of my life, I can say that we don't hold that 10 tefachim of snow invalidate a reshut harabbim, lema'ase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aruch Hashulchan wonders about the same thing in  [סימן שסב - דיני מחיצות, ופרוץ כעומד, ודיני צורת הפתח](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0271_L2)

It seems that he's of the opinion - bringing proofs - that snow that will remain higher than 10 Tefachim during the entire Shabbat has the same law as a solid wall.

Since he cannot find anybody to explicitly concur, he remains undecided, for practical purposes. In his words: ולדינא צ''ע.

That would mean that one would have to be stringent in both directions; the high snow cannot be treated as a wall to create an Eruv, and yet one would not be allowed to move items from the ground (of private or public property) to the higher snow or vise versa.

> **טו** ויש להסתפק אם מועיל בימי החורף מחיצה של שלג וכפור וקרח. ונראה לכאורה דלא מהני, מדאמרינן בבבא בתרא (כ'.) דאינן ממעטין בחלון, לענין פותח טפח המביא את הטומאה, משום דכיון דנמוקים מאליהם - לא ממעטים את הפותח טפח ע''ש, וכל שכן דאין שם מחיצה על זה, וכמים בעלמא הם.‏
>   אך אין ראיה מזה, דבסתימת פותח טפח צריך ביטול עולמית כמ''ש הרמב''ם בריש פרק ט''ו מטומאת מת, דבעינן דבר שאין דרכו לפנותו. אבל מחיצות הא דיו לשעתו, כמו המחיצות שבשיירא, ולשעתו הוי השלג דבר של קיימא בחורף. ‏
>   ואף על פי שבסעיף ד' כתבנו, דלדעת הרמב''ם לא מהני מחיצה לשעה - זהו לשעה או ליום. אבל לכמה ימים - ודאי מועיל, והשלג בימות החורף הוא להרבה ימים. ‏
>   וגם אין להביא ראיה מבבא בתרא שם, שאומר שם דמחיצה של רבב, כלומר מדבר שמנונית - אינו מועיל ע''ש. זהו מפני שבחום השמש ימסו מיד, ולא כן השלג בחורף. ‏
>   וקצת ראיה יש להביא דהוה מחיצה, ממה שכתב המרדכי בפרק 'כיסוי הדם' בשם גאון, דמכסין בשלג, דכתיב ''כי לשלג יאמר הוה ארץ'', הרי דמדמי שלג לארץ. ועם כי רבינו הב''י דחי לה ביו''ד סימן כ''ח בספרו הגדול, זהו מטעם דבכיסוי בעינן עפר ע''ש. מכל מקום זכר לדבר יש, דשלג הוי דומיא דארץ. ‏
>   ואף על גב דלענין מקוה הוה שלג כמים, כמבואר בפרק ז' (מ''א), דמקוואות זהו כשמטילו לתוך המים ונימס ע''ש, וגם בנדה (י''ז.) אמרינן דשלג אינו משקה עד שיחשב עליו למשקין ע''ש, וכל זמן שלא חישב הרי הוא ככל הדברים, ולמה לא יהיה ראוי למחיצה. ולדינא צ''ע. ‏
>   **טז** איתא בבבא בתרא (כ':), דאין עושין מחיצה ברבב, ובמלח עושין מחיצה. וזהו במלח סדומית, והיינו שמושכין מן הים שהוא קשה. אבל מלח אסתרקנית שהוא מלח רך - אין עושין ממנו מחיצה, זולת תחת הקורה במבוי, שהקורה מעמידו שלא יתפזר. ע''ש 
>   ואין מזה ראיה לשלג שאינה מחיצה, דהא ודאי השלג רך יותר מהמלח, דטעמא דמלח לא מפני רכותו אלא משום שהוא חתיכות קטנות ומתפזר, כמ''ש רש''י שם. אבל השלג בימות החורף, שוכב יפה ולא יתפזר. ותמיהני על הרמב''ם בפרק ט''ז ועל הטור וש''ע, שלא הביאו לא דין רבב ולא דין מלח, וצ''ע. ‏

In [סימן תרכט - מאיזה דבר צריך להיות הסכך](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0538_L2) regarding snow in lieu of Schach or on top of Schach, it seems that he treats "a lot of snow" as permanent, as this is the stringent case.

> **ב** ודע שיש להסתפק במדינות הצפוניות שלנו, שכמה פעמים יורד שלג בחג הסוכות, ונפל הרבה שלג על הסכך, אם נפסלה הסוכה בכך אם לאו? וראיתי מי שכתב שהיא כשירה, דכיון דשלג אינו חוצץ בפני הטומאה (אוהלות פרק רביעי משנה ה) – לא חשיבה להיותה תקרה על הסוכה (באר היטב ושערי תשובה בסימן תרכו סעיף קטן א). ‏
>   ואני אומר דאין מזה שום ראיה, דהא גם זרעים וירקות המחוברין לקרקע – תנן התם דגם כן אין חוצצין, ובסוכה וודאי דפסלי. וזה דשלג אינו חוצץ – משום שאינו מתקיים. אבל לשעתו וודאי מבטל הסכך. ‏
>   אך מטעם אחר יש לומר שאינו פוסל, דהנה שלג אינו מקבל טומאה, כדאמרינן בנדה (יז א). ‏
>   והמרדכי פרק ששי דחולין כתב בשם גאון: דמכסין בשלג, דכתיב: ''כי לשלג יאמר הוה ארץ'', עיין שם – הרי הוי כגידולו מן הארץ, ואינו מקבל טומאה. אך רבינו הבית יוסף בטור יורה דעה סוף סימן כח דחה לה, עיין שם. ולכן נראה לי דבעת שהשלג רבה על הסכך – לא יברך ''לישב בסוכה''. ו חוצץ – משום שאינו מתקיים. אבל לשעתו וודאי מבטל הסכך. ‏